# What is this pencil-and-paper game called in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, word-games

What's the name of the following children's game in English?

It's a pencil and paper game whose players try to find, in writing and in a limited time, the words that begin with the same letter in the chosen categories. Among the most common categories we find: Personal Names, Things (objects), Cities, Animals, Fruits, Flowers and Plants, Nations, Crafts, etc. In French, it's called "jeu du baccalauréat."

Comment: In Hungarian, it's _ország város_: "country city". There's an online version that translates it to English as Scattergories, but I'm pretty sure that's a Parker Brothers trademark.

Comment: It seems the game is also called Categories

Comment: @MetaEd: can you please name the commonly-available reference that you mention in your reason-to-close comment? Nobody else seems to have found such a source so far. (Also, if you're going to declare "what's the usual English word for this concept" off-topic for ELU, you may as well just shut the site down.)

Comment: @JPmiaou The pointer to "commonly-available references" was not written by me. It is canned text that appears as a constructive suggestion whenever a question is put on hold for lack of research. The research requirement is that the asker should make a substantial research effort before posting a question, and include the results and why they were unsatisfactory. This is a Stack Exchange wide requirement, not specific to this site, and applies to every question. Word requests have additional requirements – see the “[single-word-requests tag wiki](/tags/single-word-requests/info)”.

Comment: My family used to play a [great game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1233/facts-five) like this in the 1960s and 1970s.

Comment: @mplungjan, I think you should post Categories as an answer, because I think that's the most generic English name for the parlor/party game. It certainly seems to be the reason they named the Parker Brothers game Scattergories.

Comment: @MetaEd, perhaps when none of the close reasons seem to quite apply as worded, it's because the question shouldn't be closed. I don't have the reputation or whatever to even suggest re-opening this question, but it really needs to be restored: it's a perfectly valid and on-topic question for this site.

Comment: Let's see what happens @JPmiaou

Comment: @JPmiaou Maybe I can be clearer. The question does not detail the effort already made to find an answer, solutions already rejected, and why. This is a basic requirement for any question. When the asker adds this information to the question, it should be reopened, and not before. If you disagree, I invite you to get the community involved by writing a question about it at [meta].

Comment: @JPmiaou The added paragraph about Scattergories is interesting but goes beyond the purpose of editing. Editing should not change the meaning of a question. If the asker gets the question reopened, the added paragraph would be appropriate as part of an answer.

Comment: @JPmiaou you can [ask over at meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if the community believes the question should be reopened.

Comment: @MetaEd, which end of the chicken-and-egg problem do you suggest the OP start with? There's this X. I don't know its name in English, so I can't look in the dictionary or search online. But y'all will only accept the question "what is the English name of X" if I show that I've looked in the dictionary and searched online for _a_ _word_ _that_ _I_ _don't_ _know_.

Answer (score 2):

It's called - **name, place, animal, thing**.

Here's an example: [How to Play Name, Place, Animal, Thing](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-play-name-place-animal-thing/)

> First write all the 26 letters of the alphabet in a bit of paper and then pick up a paper after mixing the whole lot.
>
> We should write a name(of a human; for eg. richard), an animal, a place and a thing(such as toothbrush) that starts with the letter that you chose. When a player finishes the game he should count till 20 for the other players to finish. The other players should finish before the countdown. For every correct answer, the player is rewarded 10 points for every correct answer. If any two players get common answer, then 5 points should be rewarded. If the answer is not accepted(eg. if name of the animal does not exist), or if the entry is not given the player is rewarded 0 points.
>
> The final points only matter.

Comment: If you told me you wanted to play "name, place, animal, thing", I'd stare at you blankly. Where have you encountered this as the name of a game?

Comment: @JPmiaou I've played it as a child. It's very popular among Indians. [Google knows the game](https://www.google.com/search?&q=name%2C+place%2C+animal%2C+thing+game) as well.

Comment: This has to be the correct answer. I'm sure this is strange to native English speakers.

Comment: The best part when we select the alphabet at random. Our minds would have already rooted for the specific alphabet :)